# Can anyone explain my Apache Spark Error SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have simple Apache Spark App where I read files from hdfs and after that i pipe it to external process. When I read a big amount a data (in my case files have about 241MB) and i don't specify min number of partitions or specify min number to 4 i'm getting following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, ip-172-31-36-43.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 lost)
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

When I specify min number of partitions to 10 or above i don't getting this error. Can anyone tell me what's wrong and avoid it? I didn't get error that subprocess exited with error code so I think it's problem with Spark configuration.

stderr from worker:

```
15/05/03 10:41:29 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/05/03 10:41:30 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
15/05/03 10:41:30 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
15/05/03 10:41:30 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
15/05/03 10:41:30 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/05/03 10:41:30 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@ip-172-31-36-43.us-west-2.compute.internal:46832]
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'driverPropsFetcher' on port 46832.
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkExecutor' on port 37039.
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ip-172-31-36-43.us-west-2.compute.internal:37039]
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to MapOutputTracker: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-172-31-35-111.us-west-2.compute.internal:48730/user/MapOutputTracker
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to BlockManagerMaster: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-172-31-35-111.us-west-2.compute.internal:48730/user/BlockManagerMaster
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /mnt/spark/spark-cbaf9bff-4d12-4847-9135-9667ba27dccb/spark-ad82597c-4b55-46fc-9063-5d1196d6e0b0/spark-e99f55c6-5bcb-4d1b-b014-aaec94fe6cc5/blockmgr-cda1922d-ea50-4630-a834-bfb637ecdaa0
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /mnt2/spark/spark-0c6c912f-3aa1-4c54-9970-7a75d22899e8/spark-71d64ae7-36bc-49e0-958e-e7e2c1432027/spark-56d9e077-4585-4fd7-8a48-5227943d9004/blockmgr-29c5d068-f19d-4f41-85fc-11960c77a8a3
15/05/03 10:41:31 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 445.4 MB
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to OutputCommitCoordinator: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-172-31-35-111.us-west-2.compute.internal:48730/user/OutputCommitCoordinator
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-172-31-35-111.us-west-2.compute.internal:48730/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO worker.WorkerWatcher: Connecting to worker akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ip-172-31-36-43.us-west-2.compute.internal:54983/user/Worker
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO worker.WorkerWatcher: Successfully connected to akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ip-172-31-36-43.us-west-2.compute.internal:54983/user/Worker
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO executor.Executor: Starting executor ID 6 on host ip-172-31-36-43.us-west-2.compute.internal
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 33000
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-172-31-35-111.us-west-2.compute.internal:48730/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 6
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6)
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO executor.Executor: Fetching http://172.31.35.111:34347/jars/proteinsApacheSpark-0.0.1.jar with timestamp 1430649374764
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO util.Utils: Fetching http://172.31.35.111:34347/jars/proteinsApacheSpark-0.0.1.jar to /mnt/spark/spark-cbaf9bff-4d12-4847-9135-9667ba27dccb/spark-ad82597c-4b55-46fc-9063-5d1196d6e0b0/spark-08b3b4ce-960f-488f-99ea-bd66b3277207/fetchFileTemp3079113313084659984.tmp
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO util.Utils: Copying /mnt/spark/spark-cbaf9bff-4d12-4847-9135-9667ba27dccb/spark-ad82597c-4b55-46fc-9063-5d1196d6e0b0/spark-08b3b4ce-960f-488f-99ea-bd66b3277207/9655652641430649374764_cache to /root/spark/work/app-20150503103615-0002/6/./proteinsApacheSpark-0.0.1.jar
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO executor.Executor: Adding file:/root/spark/work/app-20150503103615-0002/6/./proteinsApacheSpark-0.0.1.jar to class loader
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 1
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(17223) called with curMem=0, maxMem=467081625
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 16.8 KB, free 445.4 MB)
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 1 took 274 ms
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(22384) called with curMem=17223, maxMem=467081625
15/05/03 10:41:32 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 21.9 KB, free 445.4 MB)
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO spark.CacheManager: Partition rdd_0_1 not found, computing it
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO rdd.WholeTextFileRDD: Input split: Paths:/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_45.mgf:0+2106005,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_46.mgf:0+2105954,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_47.mgf:0+2106590,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_48.mgf:0+2105696,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_49.mgf:0+2105891,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_5.mgf:0+2106283,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_50.mgf:0+2105559,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_51.mgf:0+2106403,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_52.mgf:0+2105535,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_53.mgf:0+2105615,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_54.mgf:0+2105861,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_55.mgf:0+2106100,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_56.mgf:0+2106265,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_57.mgf:0+2105768,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_58.mgf:0+2106180,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_59.mgf:0+2105751,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_6.mgf:0+2106247,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_60.mgf:0+2106133,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_61.mgf:0+2106224,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_62.mgf:0+2106415,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_63.mgf:0+2106408,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_64.mgf:0+2105702,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_65.mgf:0+2106268,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_66.mgf:0+2106149,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_67.mgf:0+2105846,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_68.mgf:0+2105408,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_69.mgf:0+2106172,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_7.mgf:0+2105517,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_70.mgf:0+2105980,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_71.mgf:0+2105651,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_72.mgf:0+2105936,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_73.mgf:0+2105966,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_74.mgf:0+2105456,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_75.mgf:0+2105786,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_76.mgf:0+2106151,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_77.mgf:0+2106284,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_78.mgf:0+2106163,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_79.mgf:0+2106233,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_8.mgf:0+2105885,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_80.mgf:0+2105979,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_81.mgf:0+2105888,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_82.mgf:0+2106546,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_83.mgf:0+2106322,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_84.mgf:0+2106017,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_85.mgf:0+2106242,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_86.mgf:0+2105543,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_87.mgf:0+2106556,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_88.mgf:0+2105637,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_89.mgf:0+2106130,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_9.mgf:0+2105634,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_90.mgf:0+2105731,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_91.mgf:0+2106401,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_92.mgf:0+2105736,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_93.mgf:0+2105688,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_94.mgf:0+2106436,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_95.mgf:0+2105609,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_96.mgf:0+2105525,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_97.mgf:0+2105603,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_98.mgf:0+2106211,/user/root/pepnovo3/largeinputfile2/largeinputfile2_99.mgf:0+2105928
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 0
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(6906) called with curMem=39607, maxMem=467081625
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 6.7 KB, free 445.4 MB)
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 0 took 15 ms
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(53787) called with curMem=46513, maxMem=467081625
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 52.5 KB, free 445.3 MB)
15/05/03 10:41:33 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
15/05/03 10:41:33 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
15/05/03 10:41:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(252731448) called with curMem=100300, maxMem=467081625
15/05/03 10:41:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block rdd_0_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 241.0 MB, free 204.3 MB)
15/05/03 10:41:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block rdd_0_1
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is probably in the executor log, which is different from the worker log. Most likely it runs out of memory and either starts GC thrashing or dies from OOM. You could try running with more memory per executor if this is an option.

Comment: Where can I find the exucotors logs with default configuration on Amazon EC2 instances ?

Comment: They are linked from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system hard disk space, network and memory. spark write file in $SPARK_HOME/work. some time full hard disk space, no memory free or network issue.
if any exception you can see on your_machine:4040